# How to avoid the white space shown in the image?

Tags: html, css

I have been making a website and want to avoid the white space indicated by a arrow when screen size is less than 600px. The website works perfect on tablets, laptops and larger devices but the problem arises on smaller devices.
Here is the image .
website working good on large devices:

[image]

and

website not working on smaller devices:

[image]

Here is my Css

```css
.events {
 background-color:  #F5F5F5;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;

}
.eone {
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 18px grey;
 margin-bottom: 5%;
}
.events h1 {
    margin-left: 3%;
    padding: 2%;
}
.content h2 {
 padding-top : 2%;
 padding-left: 2%; 
 color: #00ccff; 
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;

}
.eone img {
 width: 100%;
}
.content p {
 font-size: 20px;
 padding-left: 2%;
 padding-bottom: 8%; 
}

.etwo {
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 18px grey;
 margin-bottom: 5%;
 margin-left: 20%;
}
.contenttwo h2 {
 padding-top : 2%;
 padding-left: 2%; 
 color: #00ccff; 
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.etwo img {
 width: 100%;
}
.contenttwo p {
 font-size: 20px;
 padding-left: 2%; 
}
//media queries

Here is My html
```

```html
  <div class="events">
        <h1>Events</h1>
       
      <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
       <div class="eone">
       <img src="off.gif">
         <div class="content">
       <h2>Monsoon Dhamaka!</h2>
            <p>This monsoon fly high with Gill Travels and at a price that will suit your pockets .Book a ticket now and avail upto <strong>50% Discount</strong> on ticket of Chandigarh to Malayasia.<strong>Also get discount of upto 60% on booking of four tickets together.</strong> </p>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">
       <div class="etwo">
       <img src="social.gif">
         <div class="contenttwo">
       <h2>Earn Free Paytm Cash!</h2>
            <p>Sign up at our website to earn free paytm cash upto Rs.100. You may follow us on Facebook@ gillairtravel, Instagram @ gillairtravelpatiala, twitter @ and Suscribe our youtube channel @ gillairtravels to earn free paytm cash.<strong>Refer and earn upto Rs.2000 when a person buys a ticket.</strong></p>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

Please tell me the code to solve this problem!
Thanks!

Comment: Since you haven't told us what `// media queries` are, there's nothing to fix here.

Comment: You are using Bootstrap? If so, which version?

Comment: My favorite solution for this kind of problem is to create different style sheets for each media type, and use media queries to choose witch one you need to use

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this css:

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

img { margin:0; padding:0 }

}

Answer (score 0):

You should adapt the width of the .events class adding "width: 100%;" to the code like this:

```
.events {
background-color:   #F5F5F5;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```